# How to get maximum value using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a csv file with the following values. Use import-csv to calculate the highest version for each doc.

```
DocName      Version
-----------------
DocA.docx     4.0
DocA.docx     3.9
DocA.docx     3.8
DocB.docx     2.0
DocB.docx     1.0
DocC.docx     0.2
DocC.docx     0.1
```

How can I get the maximum version for each DocName? Example, for DocA.docx , the highest version is 4.0 and for the docB.docx , the highest version is 2.0.

I need to give the output using powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to treat (compare) versions as `[version]` types rather than the default `Import-Csv` `[string]` type or a `[decimal]` type as suggested by [@Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1419175/dave-sexton).
To this in one go, you might use a `[version[]]` *array* in the calculated property:

```
Import-Csv .\MyFile.csv | Group-Object DocName |
    Select Name, @{
        Name = 'Version'
        Expression = {([version[]]$_.Group.Version | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Group table, sort versions and select the highest number

```
$TableGrouped = $Table | Group-Object {$_.DocName}

ForEach ($item in $TableGrouped) {
    $item.Group | Sort-Object -Descending -Property Version | Select-Object -First 1 
}
```

Comment: Great answer as well, i have test this as well...it is working..Thank you Rob

Answer (score 0):

When you import the CSV you will need to convert the Version to a decimal, then you can use the `Group-Object` and `Measure-Object` to get the highest Version by file. Something like this:

```
$file = Import-Csv -Delimiter ',' | % {$_.Version = [decimal]$_.Version} 
$file | Group-Object DocName | Select Name, @{Name = 'Version'; Expression = {($_.Group.Version | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum}}
```